# Having Some Upgrade issues in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

After migration from 1.22 to 2.5 these dependencies issues are coming.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade the http package version in your pubspec file to version 0.13.0

Hope it works if won't then let me know.

Comment: I need to upgrade google_maps_flutter And google_map_location_picker and http also So when i have update the google_maps_flutter it's asking o.12.2 http version is required that time i have changed the http version 0.12.2 so google_map_location_picker asking 0.13.0 http version is required..

Comment: if you upgrade to 0.13.0 isn't it working for both?